# duplicate records with cross join

Tags: oracle11g

I 'm new to Oracle and have a problem.
I need to get two different values ​​of a single table , but both must be related.
For this I am using `cross join`. The values ​​are always repeated, any suggestions?

```
SELECT 
  R.RESPUESTA as "Nombre empresa",
  R.COD_IDENTIFICADOR as "CIF", 
  R.ANYO as "Año",
  M.RESPUESTA as "Cifra de negocios"  
FROM 
  T_RESPUESTA_MERCANTIL R 
  CROSS JOIN T_RESPUESTA_MERCANTIL M
WHERE
  R.ANYO = 2012 
  AND R.COD_PREGUNTA_MERCANTIL=1 
  AND M.COD_PREGUNTA_MERCANTIL=5
  AND R.COD_IDENTIFICADOR NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT COD_IDENTIFICADOR 
    FROM T_RESPUESTA_MERCANTIL  
    WHERE anyo >=2009 AND ANYO <=2011
  );
```

Comment: How are they related? Sounds like you want an inner join rather than a cross join. Are you confusing the concepts of cross-join and self-join, perhaps?

Comment: Alex reason had not needed the crooss join, I got to fix it only with subqueries

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You said "both must be related" but you didn't say *how* they are related; by the same `COD_IDENTIFICADOR`, or some other column?